# Use xclip in a launcher command on xfce4 panel?

Tags: xubuntu, launcher, xfce, xclip

I'm trying to get this command line to work in a launcher on xfce4:

```
echo "myAdress" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

[image: Xfce Launcher]

If i use this command line in the standard terminal, there are no problems.
Executed from the launcher nothing happens.

**Edit:** A workaround is to create a bash script with the command line above and add the path to the script in the command field from the launcher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is:

> bash -c "echo -n "myAdress" | xclip -selection clipboard"

All thanks go to **lloyd_b** for his [explanation.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1344528)